# javascript timed function - expected identifier

Tags: javascript

I am having a problem with a simple script that is supposed to update a page with some values(user input) that are turned from monthly to yearly (the numbers go into numeric fields created by confirmIT)

```
<script>
function update() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    var ans = parseInt(document.getElementById("bq10a_" + i).value, 10);
    if (!isNaN(ans)) {
      var new = ans * 12;
      document.getElementById("bq10a_" + i + "calc").value = new;
    }
  }
}
return;
}

setInterval("update()", 1000);    
</script>
```

this yields an Expected identifier error on line

```
var new = ans*12;
```

and i would appreciate any help on how to solve it

Comment: `setInterval("update()",1000);` should be `setInterval(update, 1000);` - never pass strings to setInterval/Timeout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The word `new` is a reserved word in JavaScript and cannot be used as the name of a variable.

The error means that the parser expected an "identifier", which is to say that it expected to see a *valid* identifier.

Change the name of the variable and things should improve. In the code you've posted I think there's a `{ }` nesting problem; there appears to be one too many before the `return` of the function.

*edit* — also as jbabey notes in a comment, your `setInterval()` call should be

```
setInterval(update, 1000);
```

It's not a good idea, generally, to pass strings to `setInterval()`, despite the advice of thousands of mouldy old instructional websites.

Comment: yeah thanks, i totally forgot about the 'new'.. now i have no errors but the nothing happens when i load the page and enter something in one of the fields

i did replace the string

Comment: Make sure your `setInterval` call is passed `update` and not `update()`!

Comment: i wrote it exactly the way it was in your example `setInterval(update, 1000);`, now i am really at loss, the ids of the fields are correct for sure

Comment: so it does... maybe it is an issue of the outed internet explorer i am forced to use or of comfirmIT's attitude to javascript
thanks for the help anyways

Answer (score 1):

Word "new" -- is special in javascript language:

line is incorrect:

```
var new = ans*12;
```

try this:

```
var newvalue = ans*12;
```

More information on:

http://javascript.about.com/library/blreserved.htm

http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm